# Devemos usar "exemplo.com" ou "example.com" em exemplos?

Tags: debate

Os sites [example.com](http://example.com), [example.net](http://example.net), [example.org](http://example.org) e [example.edu](http://example.edu) (além de, argh!, [.example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.example)) são [domínios reservados](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) pelo IETF e ICANN para serem usados de exemplo em documentação, manuais e, bem, exemplos [de código, de URL, etc]. Entretanto, vejo muitos exemplos (tanto em perguntas no SOPT quanto [na própria interface de usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) do mesmo) que usam a URL [exemplo.com](http://exemplo.com/) - que como podem ver não está reservada e, creio eu, pode ser adquirida por quem quiser (imagina o PageRank! por outro lado, imagina o DDoS de iniciantes bombardeando com requisições toscas...). O mesmo vale para [exemplo.com.br](http://exemplo.com.br/) (mas esse já não é usado tanto).

Há algum contra em se continuar usando `exemplo.com` (ou talvez algum pró em se usar `example.com`) que justifique mudar/estimular o uso "correto"?

Comment: Li este tópico hoje e desde então já usei `example.com` uma dúzia de vezes :) É daquelas informações que realmente mereciam ganho de REP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Acho que sempre que um editor encontrar `exemplo.com` deve corrigi-lo para `example.com`.

Uma das metas principais da comunidade [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) é Fazer da Internet um Lugar Melhor:

> we provide experts with the tools they need to make The Internet a better place.

Na minha opinião, ter links de exemplo que fogem das melhores práticas vai contra esse princípio. Conforme o [RFC2606 da  Internet Engineering Task Force](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) que regula as Melhores Práticas Correntes da Internet (ênfase minha):

> Reserved Top Level DNS Names
>
> This document specifies an **Internet Best Current Practices for the Internet Community**, and requests discussion and suggestions for improvements.
>
> **To reduce the likelihood of conflict and confusion**, a few top level domain names are reserved for use in private testing, as examples in documentation, and the like.  In addition, a few second level domain names reserved for use as examples are documented.

Agora mesmo o que acontece é o que segue, mas `exemplo.com` é um domínio privado, a URL demonstrativa pode mostrar qualquer tipo de conteúdo em alguns anos (inclusive [NSFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work)):

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Finalizando, creio que o exemplo na documentação está errado e deve ser corrigido também. Afinal, quando as versões em Russo, Turco e Espanhol forem lançadas como vai ser?

- пример.com
- örnek.com
- ejemplo.com

Answer (score 2):

Se é em português, exemplo.com.br (ou pt) seria o melhor, e não exemplo.com. E exemplo.com.br é reservado, não pode ser registrado.

Comment: `EXEMPLO.COM.BR não está disponível para registro MOTIVO: PALAVRA RESERVADA PELO CG` - seria o caso então de [fazer *lobby*](http://www.nic.br/sobre-nic/nicbr.htm) junto ao Comitê Gestor para que eles colocassem esse domínio online tal qual o `example.com`. O `exemplo.pt` está registrado por um particular e o `.com.pt` livre para compra.

Comment: @brasofilo não seria má idéia.

Comment: pois sim, é boa idéia, [disparei um Tweet](https://twitter.com/brasofilo/status/447858208049491968) ao NIC.br :)

Comment: Se a comunidade fizer isso "em peso" acho que ajuda em geral, inclusive mandando emails.